# react native starter project giving "TransformError" using removed Babel 5 option error and red screen

Tags: react-native, babeljs

Trying to get started with react native and ran this

```
react-native init SomeApp
react-native run-ios
```

And that creates the red screen error

```
TransformError Using removed Babel 5 options Projects/.bablerc.optional Put the specific transforms you want in the plugins option
```

I followed the instructions from this bug:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/339

And added a specific version of babel to the dev dependencies and that seemed to have fixed it.  How come the react starter instructions and project template don't have that in the package.json already - is this a bug?